# How to hide and replace a component in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-components

Hello i have a parent component (A) and it has 2 child components (B and C). Parent A by default displays child component B. Now when a button is clicked that is displayed on parent A, it replaces child component B with child component C. How can i replace component B with Component C after the button is clicked in angular2?

Answer (score 9):

To do that you can use the [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) directive or the `hidden` property.

Note the difference:

- `*ngIf` removes and recreates the element:

> If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the
>   element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is
>   reinserted into the DOM.

- `hidden` hides the element using `display: none`

From angular`s [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf):

> The show/hide technique is probably fine for small element trees. We
>   should be wary when hiding large trees; NgIf may be the safer choice.
>   Always measure before leaping to conclusions.

Check the example below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <b>Using *ngIf:</b>
    <div *ngIf="!isOn">Light Off</div>
    <div *ngIf="isOn">Light On</div>
    <br />
    <b>Using [hidden]:</b>
    <div [hidden]="isOn">Light Off</div>
    <div [hidden]="!isOn">Light On</div>
    <br />
    <button (click)="setState()">{{ getButtonText() }}</button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  private isOn: boolean = false;

  getButtonText(): string {
    return `Switch ${ this.isOn ? 'Off' : 'On' }`;
  }
  setState(): void {
    this.isOn = !this.isOn;
  }

}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7b1eWgSHiM1QV6vDUAB0

For further reading about `[hidden]`, I indicate this article: http://angularjs.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the response. What if u have multiple child components will NgSwitch be more suitable than NgIf?

Comment: Sure, you can change the isOn variable to a String representing the selected component, and then add ngSwitchCase for every possible scenario.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple child components it's easier to use `ngSwitch`. Both `*ngIf` and `ngSwitch` remove and recreate DOM elements. I added a `ngSwitch` case to the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7b1eWgSHiM1QV6vDUAB0.

Comment: Glad to help :) If it answered you question, I think you should accept the answer.

Comment: "*ngIf removes and recreates the element:"...THAT is what I wanted to know...thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Typically you'd have both components in Parent A's template, but you'd use an `ngIf` to cause them to appear only when they're supposed to.

```
<button (click)="setButtonClicked(true)">Click Me</button>
<component-b *ngIf="!buttonWasClicked"></component-b>
<component-c *ngIf="buttonWasClicked"></component-c>
```

In Parent A's model, you'd have corresponding code to set the property:

```
buttonWasClicked: boolean = false;

setButtonClicked(clicked: boolean) {
    this.buttonWasClicked = clicked;
}
```

You may prefer to use [`NgSwitch`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html) instead of `NgIf`.